# PHP regex pattern not identifying closing bracket for tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a text area of text that can possibly contain  tags in them.  I need to identify these tags with a specific string of text in the src attribute ("/storyimages/") and delete them. So for instance, if I have the text

```
<br><img src="/storyimages/myimage.jpg" align="right" WIDTH="105" HEIGHT="131"><b>(CNS) </b>Lorem ipsum dolor...
```

I just want to get rid of the whole  tag and replace it with ''. The regex pattern I'm trying to use is

```
/<img src=.*\/storyimages\/.*>/
```

but it's not working. What happens is that it identifies the start of the string ok, but it's not identifying the closing > character, so if I use preg_match(), the match starts with .

I know you're not supposed to use a regex on HTML, but this isn't embedded tags; it's just one tag in the midst of a bunch of text, so I should be ok. From what I can see, the > isn't a special character, but even if I escape it, I still get the same result.

Is there something simple I'm missing that would make this work? Or do I need to write some sort of function that loops over the string character by character to find the positions of the open and close brackets and then replace them?

The interesting thing is that when I try this with a [regex tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), it works fine, but when I actually run the code, I get the problem described above.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's one way that doesn't use regex: https://eval.in/309744

Comment: If your issue is that you are not matching the first ever `>` after the img, you need to use the `?` to make it lazy , regex would be `<img src=.*\/storyimages\/.*?>` , tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/wE3wZ2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<img src=.*?\/storyimages\/.*?>` regex.

The main point is using `*?` quanitifier to make matching non-greedy (i.e. match the least matching characters as possible).

Here is a sample PHP code:

```
$re = "/<img src=.*?\\/storyimages\\/.*?>/"; 
$str = "<br><img src=\"/storyimages/myimage.jpg\" align=\"right\" WIDTH=\"105\" HEIGHT=\"131\"><b>(CNS) </b>Lorem ipsum dolor..."; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

The match will look like `<img src="/storyimages/myimage.jpg" align="right" WIDTH="105" HEIGHT="131">`.

Comment: Follow up question: as stated, this isolates the tag perfectly. However, I can't get the string replaced in my text, either using preg_replace() with the pattern, or str_replace() with the returned value in the matches array. If I use the count option in str_replace(), it returns a 1, but nothing is replaced. Also, your code sample has two backslashes on either side of /storyimages/. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Please check out this sample program: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYzNpckZFSFdmM28. It shows I can use `preg_replace`. No idea what typo you mean, I just used `/storyimages/` to target the regex to any tag having this string.

Comment: They typo I was (mistakenly) referring to was the escaping the backslashes in your code sample (they don't exist in the very first code sample in your answer). What I'm having issues with is that my pattern works great with preg_match_all() in finding the tags and putting them in a matches array, but the same pattern doesn't work when I go to actually replace them. I'm suspecting it has to do with needing to escape the double quotes in the string. I've tried using addslashes() on my text string (it's much longer than in my sample), but it's still not replacing. Still working on it...

Comment: Check for specific characters in the replacement string. If there are `$`, they should be doubled.

Comment: Sigh. I figured out the problem, and it was unrelated to the regex itself. Thanks a lot for your help and quick responses.